# Me salen BSOD desde que instalé Genexus 18 U8

Tags: genexus, genexus18

Hago esta pregunta solo para descartar que sea por culpa de genexus. ¿A alguien más le ocurre que desde esta versión (Gx 18.180599 U8)  y mientras está trabajando con Genexus le salte una BSOD (Pantalla azul)?
Al analizar el fichero .dmp con WinDbg me indica, entre otras muchas cosas, lo siguiente:

> UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
>
> [...]
>
> BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1
>
> CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  **GeneXus.exe**
>
> [...]

Puede que solo sea una coincidencia porque estaba trabajando con Genexus.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!